# CSS Sprite Question: horizontal background position

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I'm looking at this sprites [tutorial here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites). The finished CSS sprites result [is here](http://www.alistapart.com/d/sprites/ala-image3.html). And this is the whole working code:

```
#skyline {
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 background: url(test-3.jpg);
 margin: 10px auto; padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}
#skyline li {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; position: absolute; top: 0;}

#skyline li, #skyline a {height: 200px; display: block;}
#panel1b {left: 0; width: 95px;}
#panel2b {left: 96px; width: 75px;}
#panel3b {left: 172px; width: 110px;}
#panel4b {left: 283px; width: 117px;}

#panel1b a:hover {background: transparent url(test-3.jpg) 0 -200px no-repeat;}
#panel2b a:hover {background: transparent url(test-3.jpg) -96px -200px no-repeat;}
#panel3b a:hover {background: transparent url(test-3.jpg) -172px -200px no-repeat;}
#panel4b a:hover {background: transparent url(test-3.jpg) -283px -200px no-repeat;}
```

I am a little confused. On the `a:hover`part of the code (the part where the sprites should show up), the vertical position for the sprites background is set up to be `-200px`, which makes sense since the top corner needs to be above the current starting point for that background image. But why is the horizontal position needs to be negative (-96px,-172px)? my first intuition was that if you start from 0, then the next one would start from the last one's width which is +96px. If we are talking about regular coordinates, I dont see why we shoud use negative value for horizontal position there...

now if I change all of them to positive then the sprite is not working anymore. So why is it negative? Can somebody experienced with CSS explain me this? Would appreciate any answer/input thanks

**EDIT:**

This is the master image:
[Master Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boL1m.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The position specifies where to "slide" the spritesheet to show the image on the page. So if an image is 96px to the right, you need to slide the whole sheet 96px left to bring it into view.

Effectively, you have 4 panels with differing widths. When the mouse hovers, it takes a copy of the image, slides it up 200px to get the hover image, then slides it left so the correct slice begins in the panel. The width of the panel clips the right side of the image off.

[image]

Comment: well the way i see it the image is not 96px to the right. The sprite background is on the same exact location horizontaly with the source background. Only the vertical location is different. (source is on the top, sprite is below it). considering that, you should not have to "slide" the image to the left, right?

Comment: In your image, it first slides the image up vertically, then chooses only a small slice of it horizontally so that only the section your mouse hovers is shown

Comment: You have to slide it, because you only want to show one particular piece of the big image. If you work on the first piece, starting from left, you don't need to slide. But when you work to the next one, you must slide the background image to the left, so that what you see is only the desired piece.

Comment: @Charlie:I do understand that. What I dont understand is that after you slide it up vertically (-200px), why would you use -96px to slice it horizontally? the way i understand it, it should've been +96px. The first image starts from 0 and the width is 95px, then the second image should start from +96px, third from +172px. But they use negative.. Anyway thx for the response, i just uploaded the master image up there.

Comment: I see where the hold up is. CSS doesn't have a way of saying only show image from 96 to 172. What the code is really doing is just hiding the first 96px. Your thinking of it in terms of 'give me the image starting at x=96px"... CSS cant do that. What your doing is sliding the image over so the first 96px gets cut off.